# Stuck in Safe Mode login on Windows 10

Tags: networking, windows-10, login, wifi-configuration, safe-mode

I wanted to uninstall Avast AV from safe mode so I turned on the safe mode option in **System Configuration** and restarted the system. But password doesn't seem to work on safe mode so I restarted again with **Safe mode with networking** option (from troubleshooting option). But I can't connect to the wifi here. Please help me to get back to the normal mode. [It is showing aeroplane mode symbol and it was turned on in normal mode].
Is there any thing I can do to fix it with other troubleshoot options?
**Edit** :- Stuck in login page. Denise access even for correct password.

Comment: Are you trying to log in using a local account, or a domain network account?

Comment: Enable built-in Administrator, logged into the built-in Administrator, untill Avast.  Once you do that just log into your normal account.  See my answer to a previous question on how to enable the built-in Administrator on Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

Your password should work into the safe mode but if it is not working then follow these steps.

**1.** **Restart** your PC.

**2.** When you reach the sign-in screen, press and hold the **Shift key** and click on the **Power button**, and then click **Restart**.

**3.** After your PC restarts, select **Troubleshoot** > **Advanced options** >**Startup settings** > **Restart**.

**4.** After your PC restarts, you should see a number of options. Press 5 or F5 for **Safe Mode with networking**.

**5.** When you reach login screen, press **Windows + U** and select the **On-Screen Keyboard** from the Ease of Access list. 
or click on **Ease of Access** at bottom right and click **On-Screen Keyboard** from the list.

**6.** Then use your cursor to type the password with **On-Screen Keyboard**.
Before clicking the login, press the **eye symbol** (I.e. Reveal Password) option in the password field, to see the password is correct.

Let me know if it is working for you.

Comment: I have tried that. Still has the same issue. I can't connect to the Wi-Fi network.

Answer (score 0):

<del>Assuming you can log in again (which your last comment implies): Either start "System Configuration" again and disable safe boot there or, if that doesn't work, edit `C:\Boot.ini` and remove `/safeboot` or `/safeboot:network`there.</del>

### Update:

The above is outdated (apparently since Vista). Newer versions of Windows use BCD, which is basically a registry hive. There are tools for Linux which can edit BCD like hivex (very hard because you'll have to understand the structure) or EasyBCD which seems easy enough.

On the other hand, if you have a Windows CD or USB, you can also use `bcdedit /deletevalue safeboot` after you've booted into [Recovery Environment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825173.aspx).

In both cases you'll have to locate your BCD file.

[Microsoft writes](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85cd5efe-c349-427c-b035-c2719d4af778):

> - **BIOS-based operating systems.** The BCD registry file is located in the \Boot\Bcd directory of the active partition.
> - **EFI–based operating systems.** The BCD registry file is located on the EFI system partition.

With the usual partition layout in a MBR-formatted drive the active partition should be the "Microsoft Reserved" partition (and it is on my computer).

Comment: I can't login as it says wrong password. I tried Ubuntu live CD to edit Boot.ini but there is no such file. Is There any other way I can edit windows BCD file from Ubuntu to remove safe mode at startup?

Comment: My answer was wrong, sorry. I've updated it.